# Analytic $f : f(z^5) = 5 \cdot f(z) $ for $0 < arg(z) < \pi / 100$

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms, functional-equations

Consider the complex region $ W : $ with $Re(z) > 1$ and $0 < arg(z) < \pi / 100$

Is there a nonconstant analytic function $f(z)$ such that

$$f(z^5) = 5 \cdot f(z) $$

Holds for all such $z$ and $z^5$ in $W$ and is analytic in that region $W$ ?

Notice that the natural logarithm is NOT a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Contrary to your claim, expressed in the question and in a comment to this answer, the principal value of the log, i.e., the function
$${\rm Log}(z):=\ln|z|+i\,{\rm Arg}(z)\ ,$$
is an analytical solution of your functional equation, valid for $z\ne0$ in the sector
$$\bigl|{\rm Arg}(z)\bigr|<{\pi\over5}\ .$$

Comment: No ln(z^2)/2 =\= ln(z) for most complex z. Similarly for this case.

Comment: As suggested by this answer, $\ln z^n=n\ln z$ whenever $z\neq 0$, $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, and $n\lvert\mathrm{arg}\,z\rvert < \pi$ (DLMF [4.8.6](https://dlmf.nist.gov/4.8#E6); see remarks at [4.2.i](https://dlmf.nist.gov/4.2#i)).